# how get unique values from an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here i have an array

```
 Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [gallery_id] => 25
           [title] => Our Job is Your Vacation
           [image_path] => 1.png
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [gallery_id] => 25
           [title] => Our Job is Your Vacation
           [image_path] => 2.png
       )

   [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [gallery_id] => 25
           [title] => Our Job is Your Vacation
           [image_path] => 3.jpg
       )

   [3] => stdClass Object
       (
           [gallery_id] => 26
           [title] => enjoy vacation
           [image_path] => 1.jpg
       )
   [4] => stdClass Object
       (
           [gallery_id] => 26
           [title] => enjoy vacation
           [image_path] => 2.jpg
       )
)
```

Expected array to be

```
   Array
    (
       [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [gallery_id] => 25
               [title] => Our Job is Your Vacation
               [image_path] => array{
                                      '1.png',
                                      '2.png',
                                      '3.png'
                                    }
           )
       [1] => stdClass Object
           (
               [gallery_id] => 26
               [title] => enjoy vacation
               [image_path] => array{
                                      '1.jpg',
                                      '2.jpg'
                                     }
           )
    }
```

How can i get this, could anyone help me out.

**EDIT**
Below are the table structures

table1 - gallery

```
**gallery_id**        **title**
'25'              'Our Job is Your Vacation'
'26'              'enjoy vacation'
```

table2 - gallery_images

```
**id**     **gallery_id**        **image_path**
1            '25'              '1.png'
2            '25'              '2.png'
3            '25'              '3.png'
4            '26'              '1.jpg'
5            '26'              '2.jpg'
```

Comment: how had yo saved it in database i means that what is the format of your table??

Comment: @Drudge i have edited the question check it once

Comment: I.m sure You can do this by changing your SQL query. Try with GROUP CONCAT etc.

Comment: @Adam i want query in codeigniter

Comment: can u post your query that u had used??

Comment: @NareshKamireddy - I put query in answer. Do You have word "PLEASE" in your dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a terrible way, it would be best getting the data correct formated from the database. but try with this.

Where $youArray is your old array.

```
<?php 

$newArray = array();
//put here your array instead of $yourArray
foreach ($youArray as $key => $value) { 
  if(empty($newArray)) {
    array_push($newArray,$value);
    continue;
  }
  foreach ($newArray as $k => $v) {

    if($v->gallery_id == $value->gallery_id) {

      if($v->image_path == $value->image_path) {
        continue;
      } else {
        if(is_array($newArray[$k]->image_path)) {
          array_push(
            $newArray[$k]->image_path,
            $value->image_path
          );
        } else {
          $newArray[$k]->image_path = array(
            $newArray[$k]->image_path,
            $value->image_path
          );
        }
      }
    } else {
      $repeated = 0;
      foreach ($newArray as $ky => $val) {
        if($newArray[$ky]->gallery_id == $value->gallery_id) {
          $repeated ++ ;
        }
      }
      if(!$repeated) {
        array_push($newArray,$value);
      }
    }
  }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but query like this could group your image_path :

```
SELECT title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image_path SEPARATOR ',') as image_path
FROM gallery_images JOIN gallery ON gallery_images.gallery_id = gallery.id
GROUP BY student_name;
```

Then in PHP You have to `explode(",",$image_path);`

It isn't final solution but I hope this would help You

Comment: Note that `GROUP_CONCAT` has a max length set by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable (i think it defaults to 1024 chars).